# Error: Blas GEMM launch failed: if the VGG model is not in a function

Tags: python, keras

I get this Error, when I run my vgg16 script:

> InternalError (see above for traceback): Blas GEMM launch failed :
>   a.shape=(1, 25088), b.shape=(25088, 4096), m=1, n=4096, k=25088
>   [[Node: dense_1/MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false,
>   transpose_b=false,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](flatten_1/Reshape, dense_1/kernel/read)]]     [[Node: dense_3/Softmax/_141 =
>   _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0",
>   send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0",
>   send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_273_dense_3/Softmax",
>   tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
>   _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]

My script looks like that:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import cv2, numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Activation, ZeroPadding2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
import pickle
import urllib2

imagenet_label = pickle.load(urllib2.urlopen('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/yrevar/6135f1bd8dcf2e0cc683/raw/d133d61a09d7e5a3b36b8c111a8dd5c4b5d560ee/imagenet1000_clsid_to_human.pkl') )

path_weights = '/home/viktor/.keras/models/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5'

#def VGG_16(weights_path=None):
model = Sequential()
model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1), input_shape=(224, 224, 3)))  # you can delete this line and do in the line before: model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3),input_shape=(224, 224, 3),strides=(1, 1), padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3),strides=(1, 1), activation='relu')) #input 224x224
model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3),strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) #input 224x224 output 112x112

model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3),strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3),strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) #input 112x112 output 56x56

model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3),strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3),strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3),strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))#input 56x56 output 28x28

model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3),strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3),strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3),strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))#input 28x28 output 14x14

model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3),strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3),strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1)))
model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3),strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))

model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))#input 14x14 output 7x7

model.add(Flatten()) #reshape the input

model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu')) #why 4096?? the input is 512*7*7, but why are there 4096 neurons? just because alex did it first?
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1000, input_dim=4096, activation='softmax')) # 1000 classes
#model.add(Activation('softmax'))

#if weights_path:
model.load_weights(path_weights)

#return model

#model.summary()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    im = cv2.resize(cv2.imread('images/cat.jpg'), (224, 224)).astype(np.float32)
    im[:,:,0] -= 103.939
    im[:,:,1] -= 116.779
    im[:,:,2] -= 123.68
    im = np.expand_dims(im, axis=0)

    #model = VGG_16(path_weights)
    #sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    #model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy')
    out = model.predict(im)
    print(np.argmax(out))
    print(imagenet_label[np.argmax(out)])
```

What is weird, if i run the same script, but the model is build in a function, it works!

```
from __future__ import print_function
import cv2, numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Activation, ZeroPadding2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input
import pickle
import urllib2

imagenet_label = pickle.load(urllib2.urlopen('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/yrevar/6135f1bd8dcf2e0cc683/raw/d133d61a09d7e5a3b36b8c111a8dd5c4b5d560ee/imagenet1000_clsid_to_human.pkl') )

path_weights = '/home/viktor/.keras/models/vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5'

def VGG_16(weights_path=None):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1), input_shape=(224, 224, 3)))  # you can delete this line and do in the line before: model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3),input_shape=(224, 224, 3),strides=(1, 1), padding='same'))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3),strides=(1, 1), activation='relu')) #input 224x224
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3),strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))

    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) #input 224x224 output 112x112

    model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3),strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(128, (3,3),strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))

    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) #input 112x112 output 56x56

    model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3),strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3),strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(256, (3,3),strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))

    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))#input 56x56 output 28x28

    model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3),strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3),strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3),strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))

    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))#input 28x28 output 14x14

    model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3),strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3),strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
    model.add(ZeroPadding2D(padding=(1, 1)))
    model.add(Conv2D(512, (3,3),strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))

    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))#input 14x14 output 7x7

    model.add(Flatten()) #reshape the input

    model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu')) #why 4096?? the input is 512*7*7, but why are there 4096 neurons? just because alex did it first?
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(4096, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(1000, input_dim=4096, activation='softmax')) # 1000 classes
    #model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    if weights_path:
        model.load_weights(path_weights)

    return model

#model.summary()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    im = cv2.resize(cv2.imread('images/cat.jpg'), (224, 224)).astype(np.float32)
    im[:,:,0] -= 103.939
    im[:,:,1] -= 116.779
    im[:,:,2] -= 123.68
    im = np.expand_dims(im, axis=0)

    model = VGG_16(path_weights)
    #sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
    #model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy')
    out = model.predict(im)
    print(np.argmax(out))
    print(imagenet_label[np.argmax(out)])
```

So, why does it work if the model was build in a function?

Comment: Try deleting the `input_dim=4096` from output layer.

Comment: I did, but it didn't work. Same Error